# jQuery mobile: supply parameters in hash URL?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I'm working in jQuery mobile, which is great. I have a question about supplying parameters inside the hash part of a URL.

Here's some example code. In the `content` part of the home page, I'd like to be able to link to a page called e.g. '#photo-123' and have it load the 'photo' page below. I'd then extract the photo number from the URL, and load image 123.

```
  <!-- Home page -->
    <div data-role="page" id="home"> 
        <div data-role="header">
            <h1>Home</h1> 
        </div> 
        <div data-role="content">    
            <p><a href="#photo" data-role="button">Photo ###</a></p>  
        </div> 
    </div> 
    <!-- Photo page -->
    <div data-role="page" id="photo">
        <div data-role="header">
            <h1>Photo ###</h1>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content">
              <img id="myphoto" src="" />
        </div>
    </div>
```

This is so I can reuse the URL, i.e. the user can reload that page directly.

Is it possible to pass parameters inside a hash URL with jQuery mobile? (or indeed with HTML generally - I know it's possible with e.g. the BBQ plugin, but I'd rather avoid plugins if possible)

Comment: By the way, that part of the URL is the "fragment".

Comment: Not sure if you're still looking for a solution to this, but I created a [plug-in](https://github.com/CameronAskew/jquery.mobile.paramsHandler) for this.

Answer (score 3):

You can use global event hooks and data- tags to process and store parameters for internal (i.e. between #blah -> #blah2) transitions:

1. In your HTML you can go

   < a href="#photo" data-params="id=123">....< /a>
2. Intercept the clicks on all links and look for a specific data- element, say, data-params:

   ```
   $('a').live('click',
       function(e) {
           params = $(e.target).jqmData("params")
       }
   )
   ```

In this case you are creating a global **params** object, which you should be able to access in a uniform manner from all your code.

Comment: Thanks. Afraid this doesn't work for me because I want to be able to bookmark the link, so I need parameters in the URL.

Answer (score 1):

If you can structure your hashes like #photo?id=123, something like this can work:

```
$("#page").live("pageinit", function(e) {
    var id = $(e.target).attr("data-url").replace(/.*id=/, "");
    //now you have the id, do page-rendering logic
});
```

And to catch direct-links:

```
if (window.location.hash && window.location.hash.indexOf("?") !== -1) {
    var pageID = window.location.hash.split("?")[0];
    $(pageID).trigger("pageinit");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you want to use [.changPage()](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/#docs/api/methods.html) function

```
$("[name=button_name]").click(function() { 
    $.mobile.changePage('anotherPage.php?parm=123','slide',false,true);
});
```

Comment: so, using GET parameters is the only way? nothing clever I can do with hashes?

Comment: not that I know of yet there may be new stuff once an rc i out.. you might want to see if others chime in here tough its still pretty new to me

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
$('#photo').ready(function () {
    var photoId = window.location.hash.replace("#photo", "");
    $("#myphoto").attr("src", "http://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/" + photoId);
    window.location.hash = "#photo";
});
```

This will force jQuery to transition to the `#photo` page, however need to stop jQuery mobile from trying to load up `#photofff` first.  This ends up causing a quick flash on the page that there was an error loading the page and then the redirect to correct #hash tag.

**Update**
If you disable hash tracking on that page you should be able to remove the error message display.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.mobile.hashListeningEnabled = false;
</script>

$('#photo').ready(function () {
    var photoId = window.location.hash.replace("#photo", "");
    $("#myphoto").attr("src", "http://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/" + photoId);
    $.mobile.changePage("#photo");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this fix out:

https://github.com/flodev/jquery-mobile/commit/f3b2e5d84493f3b8b27f9f423863cab2a416007a

Had a similar issue but adding this one line of code to the jquery.mobile js file allowed me to pass parameters in the URL without having to add plugins and js routing solutions.