# Get Parameters of Link Clicked jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile

I've been looking to find a way to get the url parameters of the link that was clicked in my `pagebeforeshow` event

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#category',function(e,data){
})
```

With the link looking like this (you can also see I added a data attribute)

```
<a href="#category?cat=dairy" data-cat="dairy" data-role="button">Dairy</a>
```

I've read a bunch of different answers on here and tried lots of them, but I've discovered that they are looking to use the current url of the page to get the parameters. However the current page url does not have the parameters in it (as I'm using pagebeforeshow)

And then I've seen other examples where people are manually changing pages using `jQuery.mobile.changePage` but to me it seems like overkill having to add click listeners to my buttons and then manually pass in parameters using `changePage` for each of them

I have also looked at [this plugin](https://github.com/CameronAskew/jquery.mobile.paramsHandler) which probably would work, but I am reluctant to use a plugin for something which to me seems so simple

I just need to be able to access the url or the `data-cat` attribute that was clicked, but I can't seem to find an efficient way to do it without having to a click listener and then manually changing the page, surely there's a better way?

Update: jQuery Mobile 1.4.2

Comment: I havent really used jquery mobile much but it looks like you should be able to get it using `var someVar = location.hash` is this not the case? Im basing this info on http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.0a4.1/docs/pages/docs-navmodel.html

Comment: Unfortunately not, due to the nature of Ajax Navigation in jQuery Mobile it strips any parameters from the hash so it just returns `#category`

Comment: can you use an earlier listener like: `pageinit`? something like the second part of this answer is using? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5791943/jquery-mobile-supply-parameters-in-hash-url#answer-8270252

Comment: Or couldnt you do something like: `var URL = $('#category').data('url');`? seems to be the case in http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.0.1/docs/pages/page-scripting.html under the last section *Passing parameters between pages*

Comment: To handle links on your own, you need to disable hash listening http://stackoverflow.com/a/24273699/1771795 regarding custom attr, js should be involved. Why are you using pagebeforeshow anyway? Which JQM version are you using? Edit: another solution http://stackoverflow.com/q/18817254/1771795

Comment: I'm afraid neither of those suggestions worked @Chausser I was able to come up with a work around, I added a click listener which I used to update a global variable of the object $(this) which then gives me access to the href element, but it still feels like a cruel work around...

Comment: Agreed. sorry there doesnt seem to be a more elegant solution without having to implement a 3rd party plugin.

Comment: @Omar, forgive me if I'm misunderstanding, but if I disable hash listening does that mean that I'll manually have to call `changePage` all the time for each link? I did originally try follow this http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.1.1/docs/pages/page-dynamic.html but ran into some issues, I might try solve them again as it seems to be the only way to do this

Comment: Yes, if you disable JQM navigation, you'll have to handle it yourself. The second option is feasible and easier to maintain in the future. Edit: check this freshly baked demo http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.3/navigation-hash-processing/

Comment: @Omar great spot, that'll sort it out for me. I find it difficult sometimes to find things in the docs when there's so many different ones for each version, thanks again